# confused with what i'am going to do on the shopping cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

Is there any reference for the update function on the shopping cart?
For example the function that can change the quantities of the products etc.
Thanks for advance

Comment: One little problem: You asked a question about a shopping cart but you did not share which one you use.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i use the zen_cart.
i don't understand with the zen_cart update script
thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no function that does it. The entire shopping cart page is a form and you basically just submit the form when updating your cart.

Answer (score 0):

The cart is stored in $_SESSION['cart'], which is a shoppingCart object.

You can find the code at includes/classes/shopping_cart.php.

Functions include:

```
reset($reset_database=false) // empty cart
add_cart($products_id, $qty = '1', $attributes = '', $notify = true) // add an item to the cart
update_quantity($products_id, $quantity = '', $attributes = '') // update quantity of a product
remove($products_id) // remove an item from cart
```

There are well documented in the comments. See the class definition for more functions.

Example on how to use:

```
$_SESSION['cart']->add_cart($products_is, $quantity);
```

There is folder /includes/extra_cart_actions, where you can place your own php files, which are executed during cart actions (add, remove, update).